# Independence of Polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider the polynomials $$p_1(x) = 2-6x+4x^2,\\ p_2(x) = -1 + x + x^3, \\p_3(x) = 2 +3x^3$$
- Is the polynomial $p(x) = 1+7x -4x^2 +7x^3$ dependent or independent of those given? Do the polynomials $p_1,p_2,p_3,p$ span the vector space of polynomials of degree less than or equal to 3?

This is my attempt at a solution:

$c_1p_1 + c_2p_2 + c_3p_3 + c_4p = 0$

Then

$c_1(2-6x+4x^2) + c_2(-1 + x + x^3) + c_3(2 +3x^3) + c_4(1+7x -4x^2 +7x^3) = 0$

Collect terms...

$(c_2 + 3c_3 + 7c_4)x^3 + (4c_1-4c_4)x^2 + (-6c_1 + c_2 + 7c_4)x + (2c_1-c_2+2c_3+c_4) = 0$

This is equivalent to the following system of equations:

$$\tag{1}\eqalign{c_2 + 3c_3 + 7c_4 = 0\\4c_1-4c_4=0\\-6c_1 + c_2 + 7c_4 = 0\\2c_1-c_2+2c_3+c_4 = 0}$$

Coefficient matrix:

$$A=\left[\matrix{0&1&3&7\cr 4&0&0&-4\cr -6&1&0&7\cr 2&-1&2&1\cr }\right]$$

$$RREF(A)= \left[\matrix{1&0&0&-1\cr 0&1&0&1\cr 0&0&1&2\cr 0&0&0&0\cr }\right]$$ 
This implies: $p = -p_1 + p_2 + 2p_3$ Thus the polynomial $p(x)$ is dependent and that $p_1,p_2,p_3$ are independent? How can I tell whether or not they span the vector space of polynomials of degree less than or equal to 3?

Comment: Assuming that your algebra is correct, yes, $p(x)$ is dependent on $p_1,p_2,p_3$. (You would need to do another calculation to determine if $\{p_1,p_2,p_3\}$ is linearly independent.) As for the second part, the set of polynomials of degree $\le 3$ has degree 4, so you would need 4 pivots in your RREF.

Comment: @CarlHeckman so does that mean that since the RREF has 3 pivots it does not span the set of polynomials of degree $<=3$ ? does this mean it  spans the set of polynomials of degree $<=2$ ?

Comment: Can't span polynomials of degree $\le 2$, for if it did then using $-1+x+x^3$ we could get $x^3$, and therefore everything.

Comment: @RedShift : The answer to the first question is no. The answer to the second question is also no, because you get some polynomials whose degree is $> 2$.